# Angular 2/4: How to restrict access to Login Route if user is already logged in?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have the following route definition.

```
export const Routes = RouterModule.forChild([
    {
        path: 'login',
        component: LoginComponent
    },
    {
        path: 'protected',
        canActivate: [AuthGuardService],
        component: ProtectedComponent
    },
    {
        path: 'home',
        component: HomeComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuardService],
    },
]);
```

I have successfully implement `AuthGuardService` which restrict access to a protected route if user is not logged in.

What I am trying to achieve is, if user is already logged in and accessed the Login Route, I want it to redirect to another route like homepage.

Comment: Add a `HomePageGuard` that calls `router.navigate` if there is a user logged in.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Were I you, I would probably simply implement another GuardService that would work in exactly opposite way to your AuthGuardService - only allow user if f.e. there is no session token in local storage. And then use it to secure login component.

```
export const Routes = RouterModule.forChild([
    {
        path: 'login',
        canActivate: [AnonymousGuardService],
        component: LoginComponent
    },
    {
        path: 'protected',
        canActivate: [AuthGuardService],
        component: ProtectedComponent
    },
    {
        path: 'home',
        component: HomeComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuardService],
    },
]);
```